# Stripe React Native - How to save payment method with 'IntentConfiguration' (collecting payment details before creating an intent)_

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am following a guide to fetch payment details before creating an intent.

https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=react-native&type=payment&integration=paymentsheet#react-native-setup

I can't seem to find a way to save payment methods. I have two types of users. Users that make subscriptions and users that make one-time payments. Both use an initial payment intent.

Subscription user payments aren't saved since `setupFutureUsage='OffSession` is required for an intent configuration. Regular payment intents aren't saving the card with any 'setupFutureUsage' enum or lack thereof.

---

Here is my initPaymentSheet():

```
const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
        customerId: customer,
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKeySecret,
        merchantDisplayName: 'Parket',
        intentConfiguration: {
            mode: {
                amount: checkoutData.totalInCents,
                currencyCode: 'USD',
            },
            captureMethod: 'Manual',
            confirmHandler: (paymentMethod, shouldSavePaymentMethod, intentCreationCallback) => handleCheckout({ checkoutData, paymentMethod, shouldSavePaymentMethod, intentCreationCallback }),
        },
    })
```

---

```
# Create a payment intent based on the configuration of initPaymentSheet() 
# Attach customer_id which provides a payment methods to PaymentIntent Object (PI) | https://docs.stripe.com/payments/paymentintents/lifecycle
# Add metadata, used by our Stripe Listener uses identify linked document
def HandleCreatePaymentIntent(customer_id, total_in_cents, metadata):
    payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=total_in_cents,
            currency='usd',
            customer=customer_id,
            capture_method='manual',
            metadata=metadata,
            setup_future_usage="on_session",
            automatic_payment_methods={"enabled": True},
        )

    # Return { payment_intent.client_secret } to the client : intentCreationCallback() confirms it on client-side
    # Set { payment_intent.id } in created booking
    return payment_intent.client_secret, payment_intent.id
```

---

I verified the Customer and Ephemeral Key I am passing to the payment sheet.

Answer (score 0):

> Subscription user payments aren't saved since setupFutureUsage='OffSession is required for an intent configuration. Regular payment intents aren't saving the card with any 'setupFutureUsage' enum or lack thereof.

If you're setting `setup_future_usage` on the [Payment Intent](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) it should definitely be saving the Payment Method and attaching it to the Customer. As long as the Payment Intent was successfully confirmed, you should be able to [list all the Payment Methods](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_methods/customer_list) attached to the Customer and see the new Payment Method included in that list. For Subscriptions, if you're creating them with `collection_method: charge_automatically` that should automatically create a Payment Intent for you that already has `setup_future_usage` set. You can double check by creating a Subscription and expanding `latest_invoice.payment_intent` to look at the underlying Payment Intent that's created.

It does looks like you're missing one thing client-side in your React Native code though. You should add `setupFutureUsage` (see [docs](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/modules/PaymentSheet.html#PaymentMode)) to `IntentConfiguration.Mode` that you're passing in to `initPaymentSheet()`. This is important because setting `setupFutureUsage` client-side will filter out the Payment Method types that aren't compatible for future payments from the Payment Sheet UI.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. So my subscription invoices are manually finalized by me, listening to the invoice.created and modifying it as needed.

Comment: stripe.Subscription.create(
            ...,
            trial_end=bookng_start,
            payment_settings={'save_default_payment_method': 'on_subscription'},
        )

I attach a customer to the subscription and set a trial until my booking starts. On the first invoice, I cancel out the amount due by adding a negative line item so the user doesn't get re-charged. Unfortunately the payment method is never attached.

Comment: Also I think the stripe-react-native declarations are wrong for IntentConfiguration. captureMethod inside 'IntentConfiguration.Mode' never works. It has to be outside.

Comment: When you created the Subscription did you include the Payment Method ID in your creation call?

Comment: Ah thank you, I missed that. I assumed that after I captured a payment intent, it would set a default payment after 'payment_method.attached' signal.

I actually create the subscription pretty late. Only after the initial payment intent I use for checkout has been confirmed and captured do I actually create it. How do I fetch the Payment Method ID this late in the flow? Should I just fetch all the payment methods of the customer and pick a random one? Should I move it closer to the checkout/IntentConfiguration?

Comment: Is there a reason you're making a separate initial payment intent? You could just create the Subscription immediately and use it to charge for the first payment instead of doing it in a separate one-off intent.

Comment: I wanted to charge one end-user (renters) for a booking reservation. Once it started, I would pay the other end-user (hosts). Can't charge initial payment intent of a trial subscription.  I did manage to get it working thanks to ur comments. My issue was not realizing 'default_payment_method' was a subscription-only field. Making me confused when it didn't get auto set on any successful intent capture. For anyone looking, I saved the Payment Method ID collected and made a subscription much further down the flow by setting 'default_payment_method' manually